# Binary in /usr/local/bin

Tags: linux, path

I look to see where the command is located:

```
xxx:~/mono/mono-2.6.7$ which mono
/usr/local/bin/mono
```

If I execute it directly, no problem:

```
xxx:~/mono/mono-2.6.7$ /usr/local/bin/mono -V
Mono JIT compiler version 2.6.7 (tarball Mon Aug  2 16:01:50 UTC 2010)
Copyright (C) 2002-2010 Novell, Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
....
```

But if I execute the command without the path it cannot find it:

```
xxx:~/mono/mono-2.6.7$ mono
bash: /usr/bin/mono: No such file or directory
```

There is no mono file in /usr/bin:

```
xxx:~/mono/mono-2.6.7$ ls -l /usr/bin/mono
ls: cannot access /usr/bin/mono: No such file or directory
```

Here is my path:

```
xxx:~/mono/mono-2.6.7$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

Doesn't it search each directory separated by the colons? So shouldn't it find mono in /usr/local/bin ?

If I log in as root, it works. I can execute mono on the command line and it finds it. The permissions are:

```
xxx:~/mono/mono-2.6.7$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/mono
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 8452592 2010-08-02 16:23 /usr/local/bin/mono
```

Is the user I am using not part of the right group?

Answer (score 8):

Bash keeps a cache of command locations in memory, so that it doesn't have to do the whole PATH exploration each time you start a command. In your original bash session, bash had previously memorized that `mono` was `/usr/bin/mono`. Then you removed `/usr/bin/mono` and added `/usr/local/bin/mono`, but your running bash still had the old location in its cache.

You can manipulate the command location cache with the `hash` builtin. In particular `hash -r` clears the cache.

`which` is an external command, so it doesn't use bash's cache and performs a PATH lookup every time. You could also have used `type`, which is a builtin and therefore does use the lookup cache.

Comment: hash -r worked for me. Good answer!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have an *alias* defined for mono? Check out that the following files in your home directory: *.bashrc*, *.profile*, *.login* or *.bash_profile*

... does not contain something like this

```
 alias mono="/usr/bin/mono"
```

This can also be located in */etc/bashrc* or */etc/profile*.

Command *alias* shows all currently defined aliases.

Comment: Nope. No alias for mono.

Answer (score 0):

I logged out, and then logged in again and it worked. I must have been doing something stupid. But, it works!

Comment: OK, great to hear that :)

Comment: A log out and log back in would indeed reset the cache as mentioned by Gilles.